# Resharper: Don't change order of member variables in JSON classes

Tags: c#, resharper

The order of the members can be set up in the ReSharper options in Languages, C#, Type Members Layout. Resharper is doing it correctly. However, I would like to exclude certain classes which contain `JSONProperty` attribute.

So for example, refer class below. I don't want Resharper to reorder the members in it.

```
internal class ExecutionParametersJson
{
    [JsonProperty("Factor")]
    public string Factor { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Penalty")]
    public string Penalty { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Origin")]
    public string Origin { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("InterFactor")]
    public string InterFactor { get; set; }
}
```

I am using latest version of Resharper.

Can anyone show me how to configure Resharper to achieve this?

Actually, I tried putting Order attribute in it. But that didn't do any difference.

```
[JsonProperty("Factor", Order = 1)]
public string Factor{ get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, I would like to exclude certain classes which contain JSONProperty attribute.

Yes that can be done rather easily.

Given this exammple code, note the additional properties I included purely to prove a later point:

```
internal class ExecutionParametersJson
{
    [JsonProperty("Factor")]
    public string Factor { get; set; }

    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Penalty")]
    public string Penalty { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Origin")]
    public string Origin { get; set; }

    public int SomeOtherProperty { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("InterFactor")]
    public string InterFactor { get; set; }
}
```

...then choose **Resharper.Options.Code Editing.c#.File Layout**,  the list of patterns appears:

[image]

Choose your preferred pattern.  Here I chose *Default Pattern*.  I've been adding to it in the past so it may look different.

[image]

Scroll down till you find a region for **Properties**, you may have to create it like so:
[image]

Select **Properties, Indexers**, ensure **Sort By** is set to *Name*.

[image]

Double-click **Properties, Indexers**.  The conditions editor appears.  Add a top-level **And** condition; **Not** and specify the *JsonProperty*.

[image]

Now run **Resharper.Edit.Cleanup Code** on the file in question.  All properties, except those with a `JsonProperty` attribute,  will be sorted alphabetically and placed into a `region` titled *Properties*.

```
internal class ExecutionParametersJson
{
    #region Properties

    public int SomeOtherProperty { get; set; }
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }

    #endregion

    [JsonProperty("Factor")]
    public string Factor { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Penalty")]
    public string Penalty { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Origin")]
    public string Origin { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("InterFactor")]
    public string InterFactor { get; set; }
}
```

Now the additional properties I included here was just to prove how you format members conditionally.  Feel free to remove these properties; the `#region` or customise to your liking.

### Moving on

You may want to tidy this up a bit and create a specific *pattern* in Resharper called *JSON Classes* or some such.